# Documenting together members declared on one line without creating a group

Tags: c++, doxygen

Consider:

```
struct S {
    ... // Some data members
    double x, y; ///< Coordinates
    ... // More data members
}
```

The comment that I intended for `x` and `y` is interpreted by `doxygfen` to refer only to `y` (or, at least, there is not indication in the resulting documentation that it refers to both of them). I can fix this in two ways:

- Duplicate the comment. However, this would require declaring `x` and `y` on separate lines, which is less readable, since these members are logically related.
- Create a group. However, in which case `x` and `y` will appear after all the other data members in the documentation, which can be undesirable if there is logic to the particular order in which the data members appear.

Is there a way to comment members declared on one line that does not possess the weaknesses of the above methods?

Comment: I'd suggest using [`pair<double, double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) as a container for your coordinates. This has at least a couple key benefits: 1) It allows coordinates to be returned 2) It already has your basic comparison operators setup

Answer (score 1):

Imho it is good practice in general to declare one variable per line. This avoids some confusion about e.g.

```
int* x,y;
```

among other things. I dont really understand your concern about "less readable, since these members are logically related". They are contained in the same struct, because they are logically related. If you want this even more clear just make a

```
struct XY {
    double x; 
    double y;
}
```

I know this does not really answer your question, but when I was looking for it I didnt find a way with doxygen to provide comments for 2 (or more) variables declared on a single line. And I dont see the weakness of the first approach you mention, as imho it makes the code more readable anyhow.

Comment: There are many other things in that struct, so `x` and `y` don't stand out as being related. `struct XY` makes it less convenient for the user, who will need to type `.x` and `.y`. I don't want to change my code just to compensate for something in `doxygen` that does not seem to make sense... Also, `int *x, y` is poor naming IMO. I would write `int *px, y`.

Comment: i suggested to use a struct `XY` not to compensate for doxygen but because you said you want your code to express that those two values logically belong to each other. In such a case I wouldnt mind typing 3 more characters if it makes the code more clear. I still dont understand why you say this approach wouldnt make sense, thats just what I do when i have to variables that belong to each other

Answer (score 1):

The  proper answer to your question is: encapsulate coordinates into one type, like:

```
struct Point 
{
   double x;
   double y;
};
```

Then the problem *disappears*:

```
struct S {
    ... // Some data members
    Point coordinates; ///< Coordinates
    ... // More data members
};
```

Probably after that change the comments no longer will be so necessary...

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with something like;

```
struct Point 
{
   double x;  ///< x & y are coordinates. (more detailed description)
   double y;  ///< See "x".
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In doxygen there are some possibilities to copy documentation for items `\copy...` also linking to other documentation is possible `\ref` `\link ... \endlink`.

With the `\copydoc` we can get here:

```
struct Point 
{
   double x;  ///< x & y are coordinates. (more detailed description)
   double y;  ///< \copydoc Point::x
};
```